# GDAL without GPKG in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, linux, geopackage

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and I've just installed QGIS 3.10 using this lines in console:

```
#add lines
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr eoan main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr eoan main

#public key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 51F523511C7028C3
#install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Everything seems to work just fine but, I found that I can't manage GPKG files. As far as I know, they should be in the gdal library. I've installed 2.4.2 version and I cant find GPKG format within it.

```
> ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28
> ogr2ogr --formats | grep GPKG
...

> gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4)
> gdalinfo --formats | grep GPKG
....
```

Should I upgrade gdal? It would be enough with some extra libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just installing gdal 2.4.4.

1. Donwload the gdal version in https://gdal.org/download.html
2. Unzip and enter in the directory (cd gdal-2.4.4)
3. ./configure sudo make
4. clean && sudo make && sudo make install

This is what I get after it (and gpkg work in qgis too):

```
> ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.4.4, released 2020/01/08
> gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.4.4, released 2020/01/08
> gdalinfo --formats | grep GPKG
GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
```

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, I get:

```
> lsb_release -a                                                                               
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
> ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28
> ogr2ogr --formats | grep GPKG
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
> gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
>
```

But I'm using a different source to you:

```
> grep qgis /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu eoan main 
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu eoan main
```

Comment: I'm using -ltr to get QGIS 3.10 instead of 3.12

Comment: that may be the difference but it seems unlikely